# Does the Power BI AD Content Pack support B2C?

Tags: azure-active-directory, powerbi, azure-ad-b2c

I'd like to use the Power BI AD Content Pack to report against B2C tenants in addition to (or instead of) "real" Azure AD tenants.  Is B2C supported as a source for reporting purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get Azure AD Activity Log Power BI Content Pack for a B2C tenant.